# Customizing less using twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, less

When we go to customize in twitter bootstrap, we can give values in text boxes for variables. For example @bodyBackground, @textColor. It then generates corresponding css. My boss wants me to recreate same functionality. It should accept values for variables used in our less files of our project. And then we say customize, it should generate corresponding css file. Please help me how to do this.

Comment: How so "recreate same functionality"?